How do I put a Mii in a Wiimote from the Wii Mini?
So I want to transfer a Mii from my Wii Mini to a new Wii (the one with all the features).
Although Nintendo says it isn't possible, I believe someone has done it through homebrew. I can't find anyone that's done when I search on the internet though.
Is this possible?

If Nintendo says it's not possible, and you can't find anything online to the contrary, it might be that you believe incorrectly that someone did it :) That's too little to go on, I fear.

Can't Mii's be stored on a Wiimote? Would transferring to the Wiimote, and resyncing on the new Wii work?

It may require access to a specific game like Wii Play. Checkout https://www.reddit.com/r/wii/comments/cacki7/can_you_transfer_a_mii_from_a_wii_to_a_wii_mini  That is transferring from a Wii to Wii Mini but it should work in reverse.
